# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host ,mail sending using Gmail

Tags: php, smtp

Mail sending functionality is not working in QA server(local ip).The code snippet is given below

```
public function Sendmail($id) {

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

 $mail=New PHPMailer();    
$subject = "Action Items";
$content = "<b>Dear All,</b>";
$content .= "my msg";

$content .="<br>";
$content .="Thanks and regards";
$content .="<br>";
$content .= $this->view->getactionitems[0]['Assinedby'];


$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "pass$";
$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom("abc@gmail.com", "Shanu");
$mail->AddReplyTo("abc@gmail.com", "Shanu");
$mail->AddAddress("user@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($content);
$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) 
     $this->view->status = 'invalid';

else 
 $this->view->status = 'success';
     $this->view->renderAdmin('meetings/meetings');   
    }
```

It was successfully tested in development PC.the error message as given below

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

I have enabled `extension=php_openssl.dll`.But same error.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: after extension=php_openssl.dll did you restart your apache server ?

Comment: You are using STMP authentication ? if Yes then did you supplied correct username and password of gmail ?

Comment: in linux "sudo service apache2 restart"

Comment: @BinitGhetiya -yep i restart..but its  not working.its windows machine

Comment: @ShishilPatel :yep

Comment: gmail smtp port 587 or 465 , please try 587 port and check

Comment: Did you tried port 587 and tls instead of ssl?

Comment: does your server has ssl ?

Answer (score 0):

If your server doesn't has SSL and you try to send mail this error might come.

So for PHP you can do

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
   'ssl' => array(
       'verify_peer' => false,
       'verify_peer_name' => false,
       'allow_self_signed' => true
     )
  );
```

> SSL verify peer make them **false**  [more](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1176)

Hope this will help thanks.